# Spring AOP pointcut with one certain argument

Tags: java, spring, aop

I need to create an aspect that I find hard to describe, so let me point out the ideas:

- any method within the package (or any subpackage) of com.x.y...
- one method argument is an implementation of an interface javax.portlet.PortletRequest
- there may me more arguments in the method
- they may be in any order

I need a pointcut and an "around" advice with the PortletRequest given

Currently I have smt like:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* com.x.y..*.*(PortletRequest,..)) && args(request,..)")
public void thePointcut(PortletRequest request) {
}


@Around("thePointcut(request)")
    public Object theAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, PortletRequest request) {
...
```

and receive an error:

> ERROR 10:47:27.159 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] o.s.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet - Context
>   initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.
>   mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: w
>   arning no match for this type name: PortletRequest [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]

Any help highly appreciated

Kind regards,
Dan

**UPDATE**
the method i'm trying to intercept is:

in **public class com.x.y.MainClass** :

`public String mainRender(Model model, RenderRequest request) throws SystemException`

in **public class com.x.y.asd.HelpClass**:

`public final void helpAction(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response, Model model)`

Of cource, I want to get the argument that implements PortletRequest, that is RenderRequest from the first method, and ActionRequest from the second.

Regards,
Dan

Comment: were you able to achieve this.I am trying to impllement the same can you help me? @Queequeg

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As the error suggests you need to use the fully qualified name of the PortletRequest in the point cut expression - since it is a string the import context is not available during the time of evaluation of the expression.

```
@Pointcut("execution(* com.x.y..*.*(javax.portlet.PortletRequest.PortletRequest,..)) && args(request,..)")
public void thePointcut(PortletRequest request) {
}
```

Since you already are selecting the type in the args construct you don't need that in the signature. The following should also work.

```
@Pointcut("execution(* com.x.y..*.*(..)) && args(request,..)")
public void thePointcut(PortletRequest request) {
}
```

It is a and boolean operation - i.e., it needs to match the method pattern as well as the args construct.

Comment: I dont get the error anymore, but the pointcut doesnt catch the method.

To be more concrete, please check the updated post above.

Comment: Both the methods or only the mainRender method. The way you have defined the point cut it will only match those methods where the first parameter is PortletRequest. You can try something like args(..,request,..) - not sure if that would work. You can also reorder the arguments so as to have the PortletRequest as the first argument.

Comment: I'd like to catch any method with a PortletRequest among parameters, and have access to that request.

Comment: Unfortunately, args(..,request,..) does not work. Haven't been able to come up with an alternative yet.

Comment: Has anyone figured this out? I am having the same issues with args of a given type in any order in the method signature.