# Two Pointcuts for two methods with the same name but different arguments

Tags: spring, aop, pointcut

Hei.

I'm writing an @Aspect for the logging of my persistence layer.

First some code which may show the error to an experienced developer ;)

```
/** Interface of the class to observe. */
public interface PersistenceService {

    public Serializable save(Serializable serializable);

    public List<Serializable> save(List<Serializable> list)
}

/** Actual class to observe. */
@Service
public class PersistenceService {

    @Autowired
    private SomeJpaRepository rep;

    public Serializable save(Serializable serializable) {
        return rep.save(serializable);
    }

    public List<Serializable> save(List<Serializable> list) {
        return rep.save(list);
    }
}
```

And here the Aspect:

```
/** The Aspect. */
@Aspect
@Component
public class PersistenceService {

    /** A org.slf4j.Logger (using logback). */
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    /** Pointcut to define the classes to observe. */
    @Pointcut("within(de.mypckg.myproject.persistence.*.*)")
    public void inPersistanceLayer() {}

    /** Pointcut for the first save-method. */
    @Pointcut("execution(public * save(..)) && args(serializable)")
    public void saveOperation(Serializable serializable) {}

    /** Pointcut for the first save-method. */
    @Pointcut("execution(public * save(..)) && args(list)")
    public void saveOperation(List<Serializable> list) {}

    /** Method for the first save-method. */
    @Around("inPersistanceLayer() && saveOperation(serializable)")
    public List<Serializable> logSave(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Serializable serializable) throws Throwable {

        // log some stuff
        Object saved = joinPoint.proceed();
        // log somemore stuff
    }

    /** Method for the second save-method. */
    @Around("inPersistanceLayer() && saveOperation(list)")
    public List<Serializable> logSave(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, List<Serializable> list) throws Throwable {

        // log some stuff
        Object saved = joinPoint.proceed();
        // log somemore stuff
    }
}
```

If I only have one of the Pointcuts (and the method for it) it works, but if I add the second, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: list [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
```

I changed the order of the pointcuts, it's always the second in line. Any ideas on how to solve this?

**Update**
Once I had posted the question I had an idea. I changed the Pointcuts like this:

```
/** The Aspect. */
@Aspect
@Component
public class PersistenceService {

    /** A org.slf4j.Logger (using logback). */
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    /** Pointcut to define the classes to observe. */
    @Pointcut("within(de.mypckg.myproject.persistence.*.*)")
    public void inPersistanceLayer() {}

    /** Pointcut for the save-method. */
    @Pointcut("execution(public * save(..))")
    public void saveOperation() {}

    /** Pointcut for the serializable argument. */
    @Pointcut("args(serializable)")
    public void serializableArgument(Serializable serializable) {}

    /** Pointcut for the list argument. */
    @Pointcut("args(list)")
    public void listArgument(List<Serializable> list) {}

    /** Method for the first save-method. */
    @Around("inPersistanceLayer() && saveOperation() && serializableArgument(serializable)")
    public Object logSave(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Serializable serializable) throws Throwable {

        // log some stuff
        Object saved = joinPoint.proceed();
        // log somemore stuff
        return saved;
    }

    /** Method for the second save-method. */
    @Around("inPersistanceLayer() && saveOperation(list) && listArgument(list)")
    public Object logSave(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, List<Serializable> list) throws Throwable {

        // log some stuff
        Object saved = joinPoint.proceed();
        // log somemore stuff
        return saved;
    }
}
```

Now the exception is gone, but there is still a small issue (which is much easier to solve I guess): Since ArrayList implements Serializable both pointcuts are executed, at least in my test case where I use an ArrayList.
I will look into that and post what I find, but help is appreciated as well ;)

**Update 2**

Corrected a copy paste error stated by kriegaex. Thanks!

The return type of the methods logSave(..) is Object.

**Update 3**

I changed the code to just using one pointcut and one method and check with instanceof like kriegaex proposed.

```
/** The Aspect. */
@Aspect
@Component
public class PersistenceService {

    /** A org.slf4j.Logger (using logback). */
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    /** Pointcut to define the classes to observe. */
    @Pointcut("within(de.mypckg.myproject.persistence.*.*)")
    public void inPersistanceLayer() {}

    /** Pointcut for the save-method. */
    @Pointcut("execution(public * save(*)) && args(serializable)")
    public void saveOperation(Serializable serializable) {}

    /** Method for the first save-method. */
    @Around("inPersistanceLayer() && saveOperation() && serializableArgument(serializable)")
    public Serializable logSave(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Serializable serializable) throws Throwable {

        // log some stuff
        Serializable saved = (Serializable) joinPoint.proceed();

        if (saved instanceof List<?>) {
            List<?> savedList = (List<?>) saved;
            // log somemore stuff with a List
        } else {
            // log somemore stuff
        }
        return saved;
    }
}
```

I still wonder why it didn't work the other way.

Comment: I think your code should not work. I wonder why it does. Have you really posted the latest version? Pointcut `saveOperation()` in combination with `*Argument(*)` should not compile because the return type does not fit both methods, which is what `saveOperation()` finds. So either you need two flavours of `saveOperation()` (with different names of course) or to refactor your code altogether because it looks kinda overcomplicated. Why not have just one pointcut and one advice, possibly logging different things depending on the type of argument?

Answer (score 1):

Here are two options for you:

**Application class**

```
package de.scrum_master.aspectj.sample;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;

public class TestApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        save(new HashSet<String>());
        List<Serializable> arg = new ArrayList<Serializable>();
        save(arg);
    }
    static Serializable save(Serializable arg) { return arg; }
    static List<Serializable> save(List<Serializable> arg) { return arg; }
}
```

**Aspect**

```
package de.scrum_master.aspectj.sample;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

public aspect TestAspect {
    pointcut saveOperation(Object arg) : execution(* save(*)) && args(arg);
    pointcut serializableArgument(Serializable serializable) : execution(* save(Serializable)) && args(serializable);
    pointcut listArgument(List<Serializable> list) : execution(* save(List<Serializable>)) && args(list);

    Object around(Object arg) : saveOperation(arg) {
        if (arg instanceof List)
            System.out.println("Global advice   [List]:         " + thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature());
        else
            System.out.println("Global advice   [Serializable]: " + thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature());
        return proceed(arg);
    }

    List<Serializable> around(List<Serializable> list) : listArgument(list) {
        System.out.println("Specific advice [List]:         " + thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature());
        return proceed(list);
    }

    Serializable around(Serializable serializable) : serializableArgument(serializable) {
        System.out.println("Specific advice [Serializable]: " + thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature());
        return proceed(serializable);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the first advice with return type `Object` and using the simple pointcut `saveOperation(Object arg)` is the generic one-stop shopping solution. The other two advice are argument type specific, each using a separate pointcut. If you weave and run the application class it yields the following output:

```
Global advice   [Serializable]: Serializable de.scrum_master.aspectj.sample.TestApp.save(Serializable)
Specific advice [Serializable]: Serializable de.scrum_master.aspectj.sample.TestApp.save(Serializable)
Global advice   [List]:         List de.scrum_master.aspectj.sample.TestApp.save(List)
Specific advice [List]:         List de.scrum_master.aspectj.sample.TestApp.save(List)
```

The advice using pointcut `serializableArgument(Serializable serializable)` only fires once, just as you like.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between if you write your pointcut as

```
args(java.io.Serializable)
```

or

```
execution(* *(java.io.Serializable))
```

The former matches if the argument is `Serializable` at *runtime*, the latter matches only for *method signatures* that declares a single parameter of type `Serializable`. In your example, you have used `..` as parameter for `execution` which means that any number of method parameters will be matched.

Take a look at the [pointcut examples](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcut-examples) in the Spring reference docs. In particular, I think that you will find the `args` discussion interesting.

---

Edit:

Note that you cannot use the `execution` variant for *binding*, but you can easily use `&&` to combine the two like you have tried, e.g.

```
@Pointcut("execution(public * save(java.io.Serializable)) && args(serializable)")
public void saveOperation(Serializable serializable) {}
```

and

```
@Pointcut("execution(public * save(java.util.List)) && args(list)")
public void saveOperation(List<Serializable> list) {}
```

Comment: That's why I combined the two. And [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7807143/1583320) is why I wrote `save(..)` but the examples do not explain the exception I got. :(

Comment: I guess that the exception returned because of the erroneous return type in the advice. Are you still experiencing that both pointcuts are selected when the save method is called with list as an argument? I'd be surprised if you see that error if you replace `..` with the fully qualified class names of list and serializable respectively.